# Using same fds for read/write with select in C

Tags: c, sockets, select

I have two file descriptors, `fd1` and `fd2` which I want to both read and write from. I have them in an `fd_set`:

```
fd_set socks;  
FD_ZERO(&socks);
FD_SET(fd1,&socks);
FD_SET(fd2,&socks);
```

If I pass them as both the `readfds` and `writefds` to `select` like this:

```
int fds = select(highsock+1, &socks, &socks, (fd_set *) 0, NULL);
```

and use

```
FD_ISSET(fd1, &socks)
```

How do I know if `fd1` whether ready for reading **or for** writing?

Comment: Use more than one `fd_set` (different sets for read and write).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. The behavior of `select()` when the same pointer is passed more than once is undefined.

Pass two separate FD sets for the readable and writable sockets.